# Besov space norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, norms, besov-spaces

We need to recall some Besov space norms to formulate the question.

Let $d \in \mathbb N$, $0<s<2, 1 \le p,q \le \infty$. Then the Besov space $B^s_{p,q}(\mathbb R^d)$ is given by the norm

$$ \lVert f \rVert_{B^s_{p,q}} := \lVert f \rVert_p + \left( \int_0^1 \frac{ \sup_{\lvert v \rvert \le h}  \lVert 2f(x)-f(x+v)-f(x-v) \rVert_{L^p(x)}^q}{h^{sq}} \frac{dh}h \right)^{\frac 1 q} .$$
For $0<s<1$, we have the equivalent norm
$$ \lVert f \rVert_{B^s_{p,q},0} := \lVert f \rVert_p + \left( \int_0^1 \frac{ \sup_{\lvert v \rvert \le h}  \lVert f(x+v)-f(x) \rVert_{L^p(x)}^q}{h^{sq}} \frac{dh}h \right)^{\frac 1 q} .$$
For $1<s<2$, we have the equivalent norm
$$ \lVert f \rVert_{B^s_{p,q},2} := \lVert f \rVert_p + \left( \int_0^1 \frac{ \sup_{\lvert  v \rvert \le h}  \lVert Df(x+v)-Df(x) \rVert_{L^p(x)}^q}{h^{(s-1)q}} \frac{dh}h \right)^{\frac 1 q} .$$
In each case, we use the usual modification for $q=\infty$, meaning we replace the $q$-norm with respect to the measure $\frac {dh}h$ by the $L^\infty$ norm in $h$.

The question is: At $s=1$, under what conditions on $p,q$, do we have that the norms $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{p,q},0}$ or $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{p,q},2}$ are equivalent to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{p,q}}$?

I am particularly interested in the case $p=\infty$ and would hope that for $q<\infty$, one has $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{\infty,q},2} \approx \lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{\infty,q}}$. I have not been able to prove or disprove this assertion. The estimate $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{\infty,q},2} \ge C \lVert \cdot \rVert_{B^1_{\infty,q}}$ is quite trivial, but the other estimate is not.